# How does Browser plugins fetch group member details in Facebook without opt-in?

Tags: facebook, graph

I have noticed that some browser plugins are capable of fetching group member count which is impossible with Graph API ?

Can somebody point me to the right direction of how its being done ?

Comment: If it is impossible in the API they must be scraping which Facebook doesn't allow

Comment: if you check this plugin https://mtfb.lnmai.com/ i don't believe its using scraping.